# I have the property name but req.body.name1 throws undefined

Tags: html, node.js, body-parser

I looked other answer relating the same problem but I couldn't figure it out. Can someone help me?

This is my main.js file:

```
    app.get('/addbook', function (req,res){
    res.render('addbook.html');
    });
    app.post('/bookadded', function (req,res) {
      // saving data in database
      let sqlquery = "INSERT INTO books (name, price) VALUES (?,?)";
      // execute sql query
      let newrecord = [req.body.name1, req.body.price];
      db.query(sqlquery, newrecord, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err.message);
        }
        else
        res.send(' This book is added to database, name: '+ req.body.name + ' price '+ req.body.price);
        });
```

This is the body of my addbook file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the addbook page</title>
  </head>
  <h1> This is the add book page </h1>
  <body>
    <p>Please  fill related data to add the book to database: </p>
  <form action="/bookadded" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name1" />
        <input type="text" name="price" />
        <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name1' of undefined
    at /home/cmesa001/lab3/routes/main.js:41:37

This is index.js:

```html
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser')
var express = require ('express')

const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express()
const port = 8000

const db = mysql.createConnection ({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'descarcare',
    database: 'myBookshop'
});
// connect to database
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Connected to database');
});
global.db = db;

// new code added to your Express web server
require('./routes/main')(app);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

[network tab on developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kemD.png)

Comment: Are you using body-parser? This package- https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: Are you using app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); ?

Comment: soory i'll add the index.js file now

Comment: What's being send to your server? (Check your browser's network tab on the Developer Tools)

Comment: @UlissesCaon i put the image in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `app.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` up in the code, before you attaching routes to express. Order of middlewares and stuff added to express matters. I usually first add helmet, then bodyParser, compression, morgan and after this routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is named "name1", and your server is expecting "name"

Change this one:

```
 res.send(' This book is added to database, name: '+ req.body.name + ' price '+ req.body.price);
```

To this:

```
 res.send(' This book is added to database, name: '+ req.body.name1 + ' price '+ req.body.price);
```